# При XMLHttpRequest'е его Response не получается вывести, страница обновляется

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, slim

Есть некоторая форма для отправки файла/изображения на сервер и там в обработчике файл должен сохраниться, а потом в ответе выдать имя файла.

Сам файл загружается на диск корректно, без ошибок. И Response сам тоже приходит, только потом страница сразу же обновляется и забывает о нем.

[image: Показательная консоль]

---

Форма для отправки файла/изображения на сервер:

```
<form name="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Отправить этот файл: <input name="newfile" type="file" />
    <button id="submit"> Отправить </button>
</form>

<div id="log"></div>
```

И с помощью встроенного объекта **XMLHttpRequest** я пытаюсь отослать изображение в php скрипт, для дальнейшего его преобразования и сохранения.

```
<script>

  document.forms.upload.submit.onclick = function() {

    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.upload);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

          console.log("response = "+xhr.responseText);
          write(xhr.responseText);    

      } 
    }

    try { 
      xhr.open("POST", "/upload", false);

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Ошибка ' + e.name + ":" + e.message + "\n" + e.stack); 
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.send(formData); 



  }
  function write(text) {
    var p = log.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
    p.innerHTML = text;
  }
</script>
```

Вот и сам обработчик, который был написан с помощью легкого slim-frameworka, помог мне легче обрабатывать получение и отправление сообщений/реквестов. Файл сам сохраняется, ничего важного тут нету.

```
<?php $app->post('/upload', function ($request, $response, $args){
    try {
        $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        if (empty($files['newfile'])) {
            throw new Exception('Expected a newfile');
        }

        $newfile = $files['newfile'];

        if ($newfile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $uploadFileName = $newfile->getClientFilename();
            $newfile->moveTo($uploadFileName);
        } else { throw new Exception('Error '. $newfile->getError());}
        $result = $uploadFileName;
        return $result;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $file = 'log.txt';
        $log = "Выброшено исключение: ".$e->getMessage().' '+$uploadFileName;
        file_put_contents($file, $log, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
});
```

Comment: 99% вы не отменяете событие сабмита фрмы

Comment: @AlexeyTen, 100%

Comment: Синхронный запрос стоит заменить асинхронным

Comment: @AlexeyTen а разве я посылаю явное указание на сабмит формы? или это за меня send делает?

Comment: За вас это браузер делает. По факту нажатия кнопки в форме

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, так все и есть. вот же я дурак :/